# why is my do-while condition not working?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am making a program that takes the name of a drink, its type, its quantity and its price as input. The name needs to be between 5 - 20 characters long, the quantity needs to be between 1-100, and the price needs to be between 10000 - 20000. I have made the conditions, but the `do while` condition for name, quantity and price do not work. Can anyone tell me which part do I make mistakes in?

```
do{
    printf("Insert item name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",   strcpy(newNode->drink, drink));
    len = strlen(drink);
}while(len<5 && len>20);

do{
    printf("Type of coffee [ yes/no ]: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", strcpy(newNode->type, type));
}while(strcmp(newNode->type, "yes")!=0 && strcmp(newNode->type, "no")!=0 );

do{
    printf("Insert the quantity of the item: ");
    scanf("%d", &newNode->quantity); 
}while(newNode->quantity < 1 && newNode->quantity > 100);

do{
    printf("Insert the price of the item: ");
    scanf("%d", &newNode->price);
}while(newNode->price < 10000 && newNode->price>200000);
```

When I input name below 5 or above 20, it still does proceed to the next input, not asking for a new drink's name. This also happens to the quantity and price.

Comment: Please change `" %[^\n]s"` to `" %[^\n]"`

Comment: `while(len<5 && len>20)` len cant be less than 5 and greater than 20 at the same time.

Comment: Also `scanf(" %[^\n]s",   strcpy(newNode->drink, drink));` should be `scanf(" %19[^\n]",   drink);` and then copy the string once you know it is the right length after the loop.

Comment: @tkausl, yes its ok, the loop is saying continue looping until len >= 5 and len <= 20, just a different way of saying whilst its outside acceptable limit keep asking...

Comment: @SPlatten no it's not... all of those conditions are written in a way such that they can never be true. All `&&` need to be replaced with `||`

Comment: `while(len<5 && len>20)` ==> `while(len<5 || len>20)`

Comment: I would suggest changing your loop while tests to use || and invert the result with !, for example !(strcmp(newNode->type, "yes") == 0 || strcmp(newNode->type, "no") == 0)

Answer (score 0):

You have your conditions wrong in your code, do this below :

```
 do{
    printf("Insert item name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",   strcpy(newNode->drink, drink));
    len = strlen(drink);
  }while(len>5 && len<20);

    do{
        printf("Type of coffee [ yes/no ]: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", strcpy(newNode->type, type));
    }while(strcmp(newNode->type, "yes")!=0 && strcmp(newNode->type, "no")!=0 );

    do{
        printf("Insert the quantity of the item: ");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->quantity); 
    }while(newNode->quantity > 1 && newNode->quantity < 100);

    do{
        printf("Insert the price of the item: ");
        scanf("%d", &newNode->price);
    }while(newNode->price > 10000 && newNode->price < 200000);
```

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]s",   strcpy(newNode->drink, drink));` is completely wrong. You can't copy the input before it is read.

Answer (score 0):

I saw something wrong in the code:

When I ave read all code I saw the same error with all Do - While 
Replace AND with OR then you have to put strcpy out of scanf like the example code.

```
 do{
        printf("Type of coffee [ yes/no ]: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", strcpy(newNode->type, type)); // strcpy have to use after the scanf and not in the same time.
    }while(strcmp(newNode->type, "yes")!=0 && strcmp(newNode->type, "no")!=0 );
```

replace with :

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", type); strcpy(newNode->type, type); 
/* Store data inside type, then copy inside newNode->type */
```

The while string are with two condition AND

```
}while(strcmp(newNode->type, "yes")!=0 && strcmp(newNode->type, "no")!=0 );
```

This mean :
newNode->type = yes AND newNode-type = no

newNode cant have two value at same time its better to use "OR" like the follow code:

```
}while(strcmp(newNode->type, "yes")!=0 || strcmp(newNode->type, "no")!=0 );
```